# Constraints in scrollview not working right

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, constraints

Please have a look at this picture:
[image: Constraints on button 2,3 and 4: 39, 39, 5 (trailing view to superview on all) (first button just sits there for testing difference; so no constraint on that one)]Constraints on button 2,3 and 4: 39, 39, 5 (trailing view to superview on all) (first button just sits there for testing difference; so no constraint on that one)

Now this:[image: All constraints on button 1-4 (1 included this time) set to 0 (trail. to superview)]
All constraints on button 1-4 (1 included this time) set to 0 (trail. to superview)

As you can see constraining the buttons to 0 trail superview makes a bigger gap. Ive been pulling my hair all night and i have no **** idea what is going on.

(the pics are from simulator and u can see the right edge of the sim where it stops being white)
my scrollview also has a trail. superview set at 0...

I forgot to mention... When I put constraints on the buttons (trail. superview 0) the scrollview don't want to scroll vertically anymore. I tested this, and it is the applied constraint hindering this. Any help on this also greatly appreciated.... (Just popped another gray..)

Comment: It's an old, but yet unsolved question. If you ever found an answer, could you please supply it below. I'm having a similar problem, but can't find any answers. Also perhaps you could improve your question by adding the code you have for your constraints